# Pass text file as CLI argument in NPM script in GitHub action

Tags: bash, npm, continuous-integration, github-actions, package.json

I have very long cmd command in npm script and I try to extract some part of it into text file, and then pass its content as arguments.

```
"build": "npm-run-all --print-label $(< build-order.txt)",
```

It is working locally, but when i run this command on GitHub action nothing happens
[image]
There is not errors, just nothing.

I used https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-tmate to try to run this command in terminal and when i just execute `pnpm npm-run-all --print-label $(< build-order.txt)` it is working, but when just `pnpm build` again nothing happens. It feels like something wrong with running npm script itself on github action.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was some issue on GitHub actions, this helped

```
"build": "npm-run-all --print-label $(cat build-order.txt)",
```